# How to Calculate Confidence Intervals for Moving Averages Given Nonindependence?

Tags: volatility, time-series

I've plotted 30-year moving averages across time for a couple of portfolios, and I was wondering how to calculate a 95% CI for the these moving average data (i.e., across all moving average data points, what is the CI?).

Given the points are clearly not independent of one another, I would think just using ±1.96 SD would be incorrect (as this nonindependence would be a violation of the central limit theorem), but I could be wrong and am not sure how this is done. Any links, book references, and recommended R packages/functions are also appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you calculated MA by hand without actually fitting a MA(q) time series model, then you are out of luck. I suggest you use R, [like in this example](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html) that shows how to construct a prediction interval, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this paper is helpfull
http://www.wiley.com/legacy/wileychi/marketmodels/chapter5.pdf

in page 8  we have
[image: Confidence Intervals for Moving Averages]